# SQL List other products bought and count buyers, by product originally purchased

Tags: sql, netezza, market-basket-analysis

After years of reading answers, it's finally time to ask a question myself.

I have a list of products purchased and unique customer IDs:

```
+---------+--------+
| Product | Buyer  |
+---------+--------+
| Apples  | Rod    |
| Apples  | Jane   |
| Apples  | Freddy |
| Bananas | Rod    |
| Bananas | Jane   |
| Bananas | Freddy |
| Bananas | Zippy  |
| Pears   | Rod    |
| Pears   | Zippy  |
+---------+--------+
```

I want to produce the following output in Netezza SQL:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| Product A | Buyers of A | A Buyers Also Bought B | No of A Buyers of B |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| Apples    |           3 | Bananas                |                   3 |
| Apples    |           3 | Pears                  |                   1 |
| Bananas   |           4 | Apples                 |                   3 |
| Bananas   |           4 | Pears                  |                   2 |
| Pears     |           2 | Apples                 |                   1 |
| Pears     |           2 | Bananas                |                   2 |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

..so that I can see, for each product, the total purchasers.  Crucially, I also want to see, for each product, of those purchasers, how many bought other products within the same list.  **Edit:** It's important to reiterate that I should not have any buyers appearing in columns for B if they didn't *also* buy product A.

What's the most efficient way to do this please?

(I'll then work out a percentage of B buying A, but that part's easy).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a summary of counts and then cross join with itself, excluding same matches.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    A.Product,
    A.Buyers,
    B.Product,
    B.Buyers
FROM (
    SELECT
        Product
        count(*) AS Buyers
    FROM
        ProductBuyers
    GROUP BY
) AS A
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
        Product
        count(*) AS Buyers
    FROM
        ProductBuyers
    GROUP BY
) AS B
WHERE 
    A.Product != B.Product
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  However, this doesn't seem to be working for me - the numbers are identical in both columns for each product (and just gives me the total in the table each time).  They're just ordered differently.  To make it run, I also had to add "1" to each GROUP BY and commas after Product in subqueries A & B.

Answer (score 0):

The basic data on purchases in-common is a self-join and `group by`:

```
select p1.product, p2.product, count(*) as in_common
from purchases p1 join
     purchases p2
     on p1.buyer = p2.buyer
group by p1.product, p2.product;
```

To get the count for one (or the other) is then a `join`:

```
select p1.product, p2.product, pp.cnt, count(*) as in_common
from purchases p1 join
     purchases p2
     on p1.buyer = p2.buyer join
     (select p1.product, count(*) as cnt
      from purchases
      group by p1.product
     ) pp
     on pp.product = p1.product
group by p1.product, p2.product, pp.cnt;
```

Alternatively, you could use window functions:

```
select p1.product, p1.cnt, p2.product, count(*) as in_common
from (select p1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by p1.product) as cnt
      from purchases p1
     ) p1 join
     purchases p2
     on p1.buyer = p2.buyer
group by p1.product, p2.product, p1.cnt;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) is a rextester showing it working.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response too!  Unfortunately I'm getting the same results as in Alan's code.  It's just giving me the total counts for each product regardless.  It's possible I didn't make this clear enough in the original question - I'm looking only for buyers of *both* products in the second count, not all buyers regardless.  The output table should make this clearer.  Unless I'm using the code incorrectly, of course.

Comment: @baaweepgranna . . . That is simply not true, unless Netezza is broken.  I've included a Rextester that shows it working in Postgres.